# unboundlocalerror local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

This error was asked many times but I can't solve my problem by reading them.
My code is:

```
def show_preference_list_isolated(isolated):
    preference_list_isolated = {
    (240, 323): [(164, 108),(178, 422),(152, 77),(126, 431)],
    (396, 168): [(178, 422),(164, 108),(126, 431),(152, 77)],
    (288, 235): [(178, 422),(126, 431),(152, 77),(164, 108)],
    (88, 248): [(164, 108),(178, 422),(152, 77),(126, 431)],
    }
    if isolated in preference_list_isolated:
        result = preference_list_isolated[isolated]
    return result

def begin_matching(isolated):
    preference_list_isolated = show_preference_list_isolated(isolated)
    print(preference_list_isolated)
    for relay in preference_list_isolated:
....
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: unboundlocalerror local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Comment: What would `result` be if the `if` condition is `False`???

Comment: Indentation matters in python. because `result` is indented within the `if` block, that's its scope. Only that. So on the next line (not indented) `result` is not in scope. Ergo, you're referencing a variable before it's been instantiated.

Comment: @Julien You're right. I add 'else' and it runs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the problem lies in the section :

```
if isolated in preference_list_isolated:
    result = preference_list_isolated[isolated]
return result
```

As *Julien* pointed out, what happens when `isolated` is not found in  `preference_list_isolated` ? At that point it never enters the `if loop`, and since `result = ...` is never executed, there is no assignment to `result`. So when you try returning `result`, it will throw up an *Error* as at that point it would not be defined at all.

---

So, to rectify that, your one option maybe to assign it with a *placeholder* `None` before the `if loop`, like so :

```
result = None
if isolated in preference_list_isolated:
    result = preference_list_isolated[isolated]
return result
```

---

Or, put the `return` statement in the `if loop`, like so:

```
if isolated in preference_list_isolated:
    result = preference_list_isolated[isolated]
    return result
```